# Leer variables de un archivo .txt en C# (Con código semi-completo)

Tags: c#, programación-bajo-nivel, ingenieria-del-software, txt

Estoy haciendo un sistema de censo pero a la hora de mandar a llamar por ejemplo los textos que se almacenaron en la variable Sexo no sé cómo puede hacerse, ya que en mi menú tengo una opción para visualizar sólo los datos que tengan sexo M o F (Masculino y femenino)

Instrucciones de lo que debe hacer los menús:

3. La opcion estadistica por genero Masculino debe visualizar al usuario todas aquellas personas censadas de genero Masculino, Al final de su pantalla visualice el total de personas censadas.
4. La opcion estadistica por genero Femenino debe visualizar al usuario todas aquellas personas censadas de genero Femenino, Al final de su pantalla visualice el total de personas censadas.
5. Finalmente la opcion 5 debe solicitar al usuario una edad y de acuerdo a la edad ingresada se debe visualizar aquellas personas censadas que tengas dicha edad, Al final de su pantalla debe visualizar todas las personas censadas con dicha edad.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace CENSOPOBLACIONAL_DANIELRIVAS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            menuprincipal();
        }
        static void menuprincipal()
        {
            int op;
            String nombre;
            Console.Write("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ");
            nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido usuario/a: " + nombre);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("            Menú principal:           ");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("| 1. Registrar Censo                  |");
            Console.WriteLine("| 2. Visualizar Censo                 |");
            Console.WriteLine("| 3. Estadística por Genero Masculino |");
            Console.WriteLine("| 4. Estadística por Genero Femenino  |");
            Console.WriteLine("| 5. Estadística por Edad             |");
            Console.WriteLine("| 6. Salir                            |");
            Console.WriteLine("|-------------------------------------|");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.Write("Elija una opción para continuar: ");
            op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (op)
            {
                case 1: registrar_censo(); break;
                case 2: visualizar_censo(); break;
                case 3: estadistica_xgeneromasculino(); break;
                case 4: estadistica_xgenerofemenino(); break;
                case 5: estadistica_xedad(); break;
                case 6: salir(); break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("Opcion Incorrecta, verifique"); Console.ReadKey();
                menuprincipal();
                break;
            }
            static void registrar_censo()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                int idCenso,edad;
                String Nombre_completo, direccion, genero;
                Console.WriteLine(" "); idCenso = functionCorrelativoCENSO();
                StreamWriter archivo_registrocenso = File.AppendText("RegistoCenso.txt");
                Console.WriteLine("El correlativo del Censo actual es: " + idCenso);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre completo del censado (Sin caracteres especiales)");
                Console.Write("Nombre: ");
                Nombre_completo = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese La dirección de la casa (Sin caracteres especiales (-,/,',´,æ,ñ,etc)");
                Console.Write("Direccion: ");
                direccion = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el genero del censado (M = Masculino, F = Femenino)");
                Console.Write("Genero (M o F): ");
                genero = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la edad del censado (Sólo el número, ej: 1-120)");
                Console.Write("Edad: ");
                edad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                archivo_registrocenso.Write(idCenso + " | ");
                archivo_registrocenso.Write(Nombre_completo + " | ");
                archivo_registrocenso.Write(direccion + " | ");
                archivo_registrocenso.Write(genero + " | ");
                archivo_registrocenso.Write(edad + " | ");
                archivo_registrocenso.WriteLine();
                archivo_registrocenso.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Datos ingresados guardados con éxito");
                salir();
            }
            static void visualizar_censo()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Se recomienda maximizar la pantalla para poder visualizar los datos correctamente");
                Console.WriteLine("Si ya maximizó la pantalla presione cualquier tecla para continuar...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                string rutaCompleta = @"RegistoCenso.txt";

                string line = "";
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader leer_archivoCENSO = new StreamReader("RegistoCenso.txt"))
                    {
                        while ((line = leer_archivoCENSO.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(" ");
                            Console.WriteLine("    idCenso     |     Nombre     |     Dirección     |     Género     |     Edad");
                            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                            Console.WriteLine(" ");
                        }
                        leer_archivoCENSO.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("El archivo no se puede leer, verifique...");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.Write("Si desea terminar la visualización del sistema presione una tecla...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                salir();
            }
             static void estadistica_xgeneromasculino()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");

            }
            static void estadistica_xgenerofemenino()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");

            }
            static void estadistica_xedad()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");

            }
            static void salir()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                String op;
                Console.Write("¿Que desea hacer? (salir / empezar): ");
                op = Console.ReadLine();
                if (op.Equals("salir"))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Presione una tecla para salir...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if(op.Equals("empezar"))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    menuprincipal();
                }
            }
            static int functionCorrelativoCENSO()
            {
                int idCenso;
                String cadena;
                try
                {
                    StreamReader leer_archivoCENSO = File.OpenText("RegistoCenso.txt");
                    idCenso = 1;
                    cadena = leer_archivoCENSO.ReadLine();

                    while (cadena != null)
                    {
                        idCenso = idCenso + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                        cadena = leer_archivoCENSO.ReadLine();
                    }
                    leer_archivoCENSO.Close();
                    return idCenso;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que trabajar el archivo linea por linea iterandolo mientras lo vas leyendo, hay formas mas practicas, como ser el uso de `File.ReadAllLines()`

Entonces podrias hacer

```
static void estadistica_xgeneromasculino()
{
    string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("RegistoCenso.txt");

    var lineasM = (from linea in lineas
                    let partes = lineas.Split('|')
                    where partes[3] == "M"
                   select linea).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine("    idCenso     |     Nombre     |     Dirección     |     Género     |     Edad");
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    foreach(string linea in lineasM)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(linea);
    }


}
```

Con la ayuda de `linq` puedes trabajar las lineas aplicando un `split` de cada dato y filtrarlo, todo en una misma operacion

Luego solo muestras los datos, si quiere conocer la cantidad de registros los cuentas usando

```
int cantidad = lineasM.Count;
```

Para la opcion `F` es lo mismo solo cambias el `where` y para la edad lo mismo solo cambias la posicion donde esta el dato y lo conviertes a numerico para poder comparar

```
 where Convert.ToInt32(partes[4]) == edad
```

Comment: Es que edad deberias reemplazarlo por la variable donde le pides al usuario que ingrese el dato que quiere consultar, o lo defines de forma fija. Recuerda que debes convertir el dato que solicites a numerico